# Firebase child_added event listener returning duplicate data

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase `child_added` to watch for new entries being added to my database.

It seemed to work for a while but then I noticed some issues when leaving the connection idle. If I leave my app open for a prolonged period of time when Firebase returns duplicates. I think it maybe down to the connection being dropped and then established.

Here is my code.

```
getVoicemailList: function() {
    var self = this;
    var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;       
    firebase.database().ref('voicemails/' + userId).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
         var voicemail = snapshot.val();
         self.addToCollection(voicemail.callerID, voicemail.timeReceived, voicemail.transcription, voicemail.audioURL);
    });
},

addToCollection: function(callerID, timeReceived, transcription, audioURL) {
    console.log(callerID)
    var collectionList = $('.collapsible').length;

    if(!collectionList) {
        $('#main-content').append('<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion"></ul>')
    }

        var output = '<li>';
        output +=  '<div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>'+callerID+'</div>';      
        output += '<div class="collapsible-body">';
        output += '<p><audio id="source" controls>';            
        output += '<source src="'+audioURL+'" type="audio/mpeg">';
        output += '</audio></p>';
        output += '<p>'+timeReceived+'</p>';
        output += '<p>'+transcription+'</p>';   
        output += '</div>';     
        output += '</li>';
        $('.collapsible').append(output);
        $('.collapsible').collapsible();
},
```

Comment: That should definitely not be the case.  You're sure getVoicemailList is only ever called once?  The Firebase SDK is pretty careful about not raising duplicate events.  Can you specify the version of the Firebase SDK you're using and provide a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, then it's something I've come across a few times. I believe the trick is to `.empty()` the existing data from within the `.on` call.

As an example, on my site we have goals that users can add. When they add a new *Goal* the `.on` call adds a new *Goal* to the bottom of their list.

I was having an issue where deleting a *Goal* would then duplicate the UI data.

In order to address the issue, I moved `$(#goals").empty();` to within the `.on` call.

```
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + user).on('value', function(snapshot) {
    $("#goals").empty(); // This removes all all previously added goals

    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
        var id = data.key;
        var desc = data.val().desc;
        var url = data.val().url || "https://unsplash.it/400?image=" + getRandomNumber();
        displayGoal(id,desc,url);
    });
// If you need to append anything after all the data has been added you can do it here. e.g. $("#goals").append("</div>");
  });
```

I suspected that doing this would force all relevant UI items to reload but they don't. If I add a *Goal* it just pops up on the bottom of the list, if I remove a *Goal* the UI just removes the goal without any reloading or duplication.

So in your case you would add `$('.collapsible').empty();` after the `.on` call and before `var voicemail = snapshot.val();`.

Note: Previously I would call `$("#goals").empty()` prior to the `.on` call.